# Selecting data from a table based on data from two others SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: users, games and players. For simplicity's sake, I will say that the tables look like this:

**users**

```
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

**games**

```
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

**players**

```
game_id int,
user_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (game_id) REFERENCES (games.id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES (users.id)
```

I need to select `users.id` where `players.game_id` is 1

so far I have tried

```
SELECT users.id FROM users, game_users WHERE players.id = 1
```

and also some `SELECT` statements with `INNER JOIN`s but to no avail.

Comment: Where is game_users?

Comment: @JeroenHeier woops wrong name! fixed it now

Comment: `players` table doesnt have `id` field, i think i answer too fast. Seem like you dont have the proper question yet.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if only need `user_id` don't need `JOIN` just

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM players
WHERE game_id =1
```

Now if you need the names a single `JOIN` will work

```
SELECT users.name
FROM players
JOIN users
  ON player.user_id = users.id
WHERE game_id =1
```

Comment: One would think that's more than just a simple select. I'd say they want to, eg, get the name of such player - and some other info from game.

Comment: @FirstOne I tought the same. But I first answer the question and then add some bonus knowledge ;)

Comment: Yeah, but I mean... the title... The first query from this answer is probably not it. Anyways....

Comment: @FirstOne You are right, OP need to improve his question. I try to answer too soon.

Answer (score 0):

you must have a join key to join users and games. as

```
...WHERE game_users.id = 1 AND users.id=game_users.id
```

> And you don't have a table called game_users

Comment: It _does_ work to select data from two tables using a WHERE, but it's better to use one of the `join` types - such as `inner join` to separate join conditions of actual `where` conditions. It makes the query cleaner and prevents errors on multiple conditions.

Comment: see my comment on the main post. I meant `players` not `game_users`

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47913173/edit) your answer at any time with the text under it.